# Regex for getting WordPress version

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, parsing

I would like if anyone could help me with a regex or any method in PHP for getting WordPress version in readme.html file like this one:

```
<h1 id="logo" style="text-align: center">
<img alt="WordPress" src="wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.png" />
<br /> Version 2.8.1
 </h1>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Pure Regex

```
preg_match("/Version\s+([\d.]+)/", $html, $match);
$version = $match[1];
```

#### With DOMDocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$text = trim($doc->getElementsByTagName("h1")->item(0)->textContent);
$index = strrpos($text, " ");
$version = substr($text, $index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need that. Instead use `get_bloginfo('version');`

`get_bloginfo('version')` - Returns the WordPress Version you use. This data is retrieved from the '$wp_version' variable set in wp-includes/version.php.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo